# Verifiy if a vector field is Hamiltonian with respect to the standard symplectic form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry, hamilton-equations

I have the following vector field defined over the manifold $M=\mathbb{R}^2 -(0,0)$:

$X(x,y) = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\partial _x + \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\partial _y.$

I have found that $f(x,y) = \tan ^{-1} (y/x)$ is such that the vector field defined by $f$ as $[\partial_y f(x,y), -\partial_x f(x,y) ]=X_f$ is such that $X_f$ coincides with $X$.

Is this enough to say that X is a Hamiltonian vector field with respect to the standard symplectic form?

Comment: This does not prove that $X$ is Hamiltonian, because $f$ is not defined everywhere on $M$.

Comment: You mean that f is not defined on the lines $y = (\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi)x, \;k\in\mathbb{Z}$ right? So what should I do? Does this fact imply that it is not Hamiltonian?

Comment: Your $f$ is undefined only where $x=0$ and at those points you define it to be $\pi/2$ for $y>0$ and $-\pi/2$ for $y<0$. This extended function is smooth on all the plane except $(0,0)$ and does the job.

Comment: Ok, at x=0 we can extend it smoothly as you showed, but can we ignore the points I mentioned above? In the domain of the $tan^{-1}$ all the values like $\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$ needs to be excluded.

Comment: $\tan^{-1}$ is well defined for all real values. I think you are thinking of $\tan$. But I realized there is indeed a problem with the extension anyways and the discontinuity cannot be avoided. Your function is basically the polar angle. You can fix the problem where $x=0$ and $y>0$ by extending by $\pi/2$ from the positive $x$ and then taking $f(x,y)=\tan^{-1}(y/x)+\pi$ for $x<0$ to fix the discontinuity there. But doing that you create a bigger jump on $x=0,y<0$ (a jump of $2\pi$ Units..) and you would have to move up to the next branch of $\tan^{-1}$.. Let me think about it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, obviously I was thinking about the tangent function instead of its inverse. By the way, in case there exists a smooth extension of such a potential function whose Hamiltonian vector field is my $X$ then I can conclude that $X$ is Hamiltonian, but in case I cannot find one can I conclude it is not Hamiltonian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is enough. For a vector field to be Hamiltonian all you need is to find a Hamiltonian (in your case $f$) such that your field is obtained as
$$
X=Idf
$$
where $I$ is the identification mapping between 1-forms and vector fields via the symplectic structure. In your case, that matrix has rows $(0,1)$ and $(-1,0)$ and the coordinates of $df$ are $(\partial_xf,\partial_yf)$. You certainly get $X$ when you perform the multiplication, therefore $X$ is a Hamiltonian field